# How to add milliseconds to a datetime object

Tags: python

I created a datetime object like that:

```
dt = datetime(2020,2, 3, 10, 0, 0)
```

which gives me the following output:
`2020-02-03 10:00:00`

But how can I add milliseconds to that?
So that my output looks like:
`2020-02-03 10:00:00:000`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try adding a non-integer portion to the seconds?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, what do you mean by non-integer portion? can you give an example?

Comment: 0.765 has a non-integer portion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Use `strftime()` to print your datetime in whatever format you want.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

The built-in Datetime only really supports six-digit microseconds using `strftime()`, with the format code `%f`:

```
dt = datetime(2020,2, 3, 10, 0, 0)
dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')
# '2020-02-03 10:00:00:000000'
```

You can use a string slice to cut off the latter three digits if you want (leaving only the milliseconds):

```
dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')[:-3]
'2020-02-03 10:00:00:000'
```

Comment: Beat me to it :-)

Comment: Here's a nice reference for the strftime directives: https://strftime.org/